# Странная ошибка с UNION и ORDER BY: ORA-00904: "X": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

Этот запрос полностью стандартный практически в любой БД (не считая таблицы `dual`):

```
select 'A' as x from dual union all
select 'B'      from dual
order by x asc;

X
-
A
B
```

А этот запрос тоже является вполне стандартным SQL, но не работает в Oracle:

```
select 'A' as x from dual union all
select 'B'      from dual union all
select 'C'      from dual union all
select 'D'      from dual union all
select 'E'      from dual
order by x asc
```

> ORA-00904: "X": invalid identifier

А вот такой работает:

```
select 'A' as x from dual union all
select 'B'      from dual union all
select 'C'      from dual union all
select 'D' as x from dual union all
select 'E'      from dual
order by x asc;

X
-
A
B
C
D
E
```

Вобщем, перепробовав различные варианты выяснил, что если выборок в союзе более двух, то как минимум первя выборка и *предпоследняя* (именно предпоследняя, а не последняя или не пред-предпоследняя) выборка должны иметь псевдоним столбца [все примеры на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2260d82b80f09aaf47ed72d59f917392).

**Вопрос:**

Является ли это (известной?) ошибкой в парсере Oracle SQL, или есть какая-то очень тонкая деталь в синтаксисе языка, которая абсолютно точно требует, чтобы первая и предпоследнияя выборка союза содержали псевдоним столбца, на который ссылается клауза `ORDER BY`?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Curious issue with Oracle UNION and ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25387951) от участника [@Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/25387951

Answer (score 3):

Это не совсем ответ на вопрос, почему неожидаемое поведение в запросе, но его можно легко переписать следующим образом (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6878108026caeb3736b92d5b7c19d33d)):

```
with t (x) as (
    select 'A' from dual union all
    select 'B' from dual union all
    select 'C' from dual
)
select * from t
order by x asc
```

Так надо указать псевдоним столбца `x` только один раз, и этот запрос никогда не должен завершиться ошибкой недопустимого идентификатора.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25391886) от участника [@tbone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534120/tbone)</sub>

Comment: или использовать сортировку по номеру колонки order by 1 asc;

Comment: хм, в процессе тестов заметил, что фраза as x не равна получается "x" https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=11e9c3fad6e2a7eae8daf331cfc7f33b, всегда казалось, что они аналогичны

Comment: @NMD Так всегда было, x != "x", потому что без кавычек идентификатор без учёта регистра, т.е. [х == Х](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=605df4ffe42b105fce8e14bd6e362b0e).

Comment: ага, теперь буду знать, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что это ошибка парсера (или "особенность"), а не требование языка SQL.

На MOS (*My Oracle Support*), насколько помню, был открыт инцидент 14196463, но закрыт без конечного решения. Этот также упоминается в ветке [MOS Community 3561546](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3561546). Для просмотра любой из тем нужна учетная запись MOS, или по крайней мере, базовая учетная запись Oracle.

Это также обсуждалось [в ветке OTN](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2471511). Там также не так много информации, но она предполагает, что такое поведение существовало по крайней мере до версии 9.2.0.8, а возможно, и гораздо раньше.

[В документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Sorting-Query-Results.html#GUID-E45EF993-20AC-4552-860C-4D74EADB5BF2) не совсем всё ясно, но и не указано явно, где должен стоять псевдоним:

> For compound queries containing set operators `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `MINUS` или `UNION ALL`,  the `ORDER BY` clause must specify positions *or aliases* rather than explicit expressions. Also, the ORDER BY clause can appear only in the last component query. The ORDER BY clause orders all rows returned by the entire compound query.

> Для составных запросов, содержащих операторы множеств `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `MINUS` или `UNION ALL`, в клаузе `ORDER BY` должны указываться позиции или псевдонимы, а не явные выражения. Кроме того, условие `ORDER BY` может встречаться только в последнем компоненте запроса. Предложение `ORDER BY` упорядочивает все строки, возвращаемые всем составным запросом.

В запросе есть псевдоним столбца и он используется, нигде не говорится о том, что надо использовать псевдоним в каких-то конкретных компонентах.

Поведение кажется противоречит тому, что псевдоним действителен для конечной проекции запроса, особенно в сочетании с общим правилом о том, что псевдоним этой конечной проекции запроса действителен только в клаузе `ORDER BY`.

---

*Прим.ред.:* в подглаве [Restrictions on the Set Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.html#GUID-B64FE747-586E-4513-945F-80CB197125EE) указано явно, где должен быть указан псевдоним столбца:

> If the select list *preceding* the set operator contains an expression, then you must provide a column alias for the expression in order to refer to it in the *order_by_clause*.

Все выборки множества включая предпоследнюю должны указывать псевдоним столбца, так как за ними следует оператор множества. Только последняя выборка избавлена от этого ограничения.

Возможность не указывать псевдоним столбца в выборках множества между первой и предпоследней противоречит этому пункту документации и не должна использоваться.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390187) от участника [@Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

А так работает:

```
select 'A' as x from dual union all
select 'B'      from dual union all
select 'C'      from dual union all
select 'D'      from dual union all
select 'E'      from dual
order by 1 asc
```

Comment: Так конечно будет рабтать. Но в вопросе идёт речь именно об идентификаторах для сортировки и почему такое протоворечивое поведение. Хотя, надо отметить, такое решения может будет полезным, потому что большинство нагугливших эту тему ищут именнно быстрое решение, и не заинтересованы читать всю эту эпопею.